# MySQL - How to show nickname (if there is, else just name) behind name?

Tags: mysql

Trying to display client_nickname if there is with brackets after client_name, however if client_nickname is NULL, also display the client_name still. Unable to display client_name who does not have nickname.

Tried WHERE statement but still only display names which has nicknames.

`this is a dummy database i created randomly`

```
CREATE TABLE client ( 
client_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
client_nickname VARCHAR (30),
client_mobile int(10), 
client_home int(10),
client_office int(10)
); 

INSERT INTO client (client_id, firstname, lastname, client_nickname, client_mobile, client_home, client_office) 
VALUES ('1', 'Doe', 'John', 'Johnny', '11223344',NULL, '66778899'); 
INSERT INTO client (client_id, firstname, lastname, client_nickname, client_mobile, client_home, client_office) 
VALUES ('2', 'Mary', 'Lee', NULL, '99887766','44556677', '66778899'); 
INSERT INTO client (client_id, firstname, lastname, client_nickname, client_mobile, client_home, client_office) 
VALUES ('3', 'Dreylan', 'Zhou', 'LilMonster', NULL, NULL, '66770000');
```

`The code I worked out so far to achieve what i want`

```
SELECT CONCAT (firstname, " ", lastname, ' (', client_nickname, ')') AS client_name
FROM client;
```

I expected a column "client_name" with all 3 client names like this:

```
Doe John (Johnny)
Mary Lee
Dreylan Zhou (LilMonster)
```

but actual output is only:

```
Doe John (Johnny)
Dreylan Zhou (LilMonster)
```

Comment: From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat: *CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you need  a check for null

```
SELECT case when  client_nickname is null  
          then CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)
          else  CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname, ' (', client_nickname, ')')
        end AS client_name
FROM client;
```